# Rails | Validate email address wth specific extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, email

Is there a way to validate email addresses such as `'myemail@mydomain.com'` ?

So I should check if user has `@mydomain.com` extension on signup? How would regex code would look like?

This is what I am using currently,  would like to add `user.type = special` if validation passes `@mydomain.com` if else `user.type = normal`

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add model level validation on email attribute

```
validates :email, format: { with: /@mydomain\.com\z/i }
```

However the above regex doesn't put any restrictions on part of email before `@`

Edit:

You will have to add a before_create action which does check for @mydomain.com

```
before_create :set_user_type


def set_user_type
    if /@mydomain\.com\z/i.match(email)
        self.type = :special
    else
        self.type = :normal
    end
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine your & my solution?

Comment: Or when I use before_create, it means it already passes the validation ?

Comment: Yes, also you can go with before_save instead of before_create, because it handles update case too

Comment: Check the order of callbacks here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html